# Installing pear not working

Tags: pear, phpcodesniffer

Hello I'm trying to install pear to be able to install Codesniffer. I read that it was fairly easy to do so apparently all I had to do was

> sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer

Somehow this didnt work, i got this error

> Pear: command not found

My current system is osx 10.10.5

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't installed PEAR yet.

PEAR (http://pear.php.net/) is a system that allows you to install packages like PHP_CodeSniffer. When you install PEAR, you'll get that `pear` command available to you and the PHPCS install command should work fine.

Information about installing PEAR can be found here: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php

PEAR decides where to put things like the `phpcs` script, the unit tests, and the documentation. If you don't have a preference about where these things should go, just use the defaults.